# Refining Expression Evaluation (proposal n4228 c++ 17)

Tags: c++, c++17

Reading the proposal n4228  I read that the following code:

```
void f()
{
 std::string s = "but I have heard it works even if you don't believe in it";
 s.replace(0, 4, "").replace(s.find("even"), 4, "only").replace(s.find(" don't"), 6, "");
 assert(s == "I have heard it works only if you believe in it");
}
```

is subject to the unspecified order of evaluation and that its vulnerability had only been discovered recently by a tool.

Where is the problem? Maybe `s.find("even")` and `s.find(" don't")` are evaluated in a order different of what anybody aspects? Before any `replaces` take place?

Does anybody known which is the tool that discovers the problem?

Comment: Hint: Will the first find return an iterator to the first char of 'even' or to the space after it?

Comment: *"Maybe s.find("even") and s.find(" don't") are evaluated in a order different of what anybody expects"*. Bingo. Those can be evaluated in any order. So if the order of evaluation matters. Sequence them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. By the rules of C++-pre-17, the two calls to `s.find` can be executed before *any* of the replace calls. And since the replace calls modify the string, they can cause the indices returned by `find` no longer be valid by the time they are used.

The (unfortunately weaker) rules voted into the C++17 CD will prevent this, and the code will work as expected.